# Flask: Constantly getting 404 error

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I'm constantly getting 404 error when trying to go to www.root.com/website (example). Flask do renders the the error handler, but do not the '/' route or any other i defined in the app. This used to work a few month ago:

app.py:

```
import os
import datetime

from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, session
from flask import jsonify
from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth

from mod_db import db
from mod_form import form

application = Flask(__name__)
application.debug = False
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True
dir_route = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
base_dir = '' + dir_route.split('/')[-1]

[...]

@application.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('cover.html', bd=base_dir)

@application.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name root.com www.root.com;
        # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved Permanently response.
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name root.com www.root.com;
    root /var/www/KRAKEN/public;
    error_log /var/www/KRAKEN/public/nginx.error.log;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/root.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/root.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
    # modern configuration. tweak to your needs.
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'yadayada';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
    # OCSP Stapling ---
    # fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;


    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/root.com/fullchain.pem;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;

        location / {
                index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
        location /website {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix:///run/uwsgi/website.sock;
        }
        location /website/static {
                root /var/www/KRAKEN/public/website/static/;
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }
}
```

App structure:

/var/www/KRAKEN/public/website/

```
.
├── app.py
├── website.ini
├── bin
├── include
├── lib
├── mod_db
├── mod_form
├── multimedia
├── static
├── templates
└── uwsgi.log
```

Comment: Why don't you try creating a before_request method with the @application.before_request decorator, and have that method print out the url being requested so you can be sure that /website is, in fact, being interpreted as "/" in your application.  My suspicion is that nginx isn't stripping /website from the route being requested, so your application is getting a request for /website (not / ) and you don't have a route for that.

Comment: @ChristopherShroba than you Chris. Tried to get an example of what you suggest but couldnt find any, care to elaborate? Thanks a lot.

Comment: i did: @application.before_request
def test():
    return str(request.url)

Got an error.

Comment: Here's an example of what I mean; try copying my before_request function to yours and see what the route is: https://gist.github.com/chrisshroba/f7c7db1e19e6d8f9989ebbeb2a72e9d4

Comment: Thanks. I just got 502 Bad Gateway errors.

Comment: You only copied the before_request function, right? So you're saying without the before_request function, you get a 404 when you request /website, but with the before_request function, you get a 502 bad gateway?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Is there an error logged in your nginx error logs?

Comment: [error] 23017#23017: *282 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from                                                 upstream, client: 181.47.19.161, server: root.com, request: "GET /website/ HTTP/2.0", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///ru                                                n/uwsgi/website.sock:", host: "www.root.com"

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really know what's going on here :( It seems very weird that just having a before_request method would cause such an issue.  My only advice would be to try changing your `@application.route("/")` to say `@application.route("/website")` and remove the before_request method.  You can also try googling that nginx error.  Sorry I couldn't be more help, good luck!

Comment: That does not work either. Dont worry man! I appreciate your help!

Comment: @ChristopherShroba hey, i decided to take another look on this, put your code and got "the route is: none" in the uwsgi log file.

Comment: Something fisky is going on with the site root. I cant configure it with APPLICATION_ROOT, had to put bu hand on the routes. I'll post another question.